# Variables being set to null for no apparent reason

Tags: java, sql, javafx, null

I am working on a project which requires a login feature and I have pretty much got the whole thing set up and working right down to the final check.

So under the handleLogin event the JavaFX GUI receives input of a username and password which is first stored into userU and userP in GertLogin Class. Then the username entered is cross referenced with the available username present in the database in the getData method of DBMod. This method returns the username and password corresponding to the username entered by the user and stored in dbU and dbP in the GetLogin Class. Then what should occur is the two passwords are compared and if they match then the login is successful.

However, somewhere between completing the getData method and calling the checkData method both variable dbU and dbP are set to null and I can't find where or why they would do that when both userU and userP are stored just fine.

Can anyone see where exactly this is happening and why?

Home FXMLController:

```
package estorage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HomeController implements Initializable {

    String username;
    String password;
    GetLogin login = new GetLogin(username, password);

    @FXML
    private Label registerPane;
    @FXML
    private Button btnLogin;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtUsername;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField txtPassword;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

    @FXML
    private void handleRegisterScreen(MouseEvent event) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Register.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
            Stage stage = new Stage();

            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
            ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to cretae new window", e);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleLogin(ActionEvent event) {
        username = txtUsername.getText();
        password = txtPassword.getText();
        login.userDetails(username, password);
        login.getDBDetails(username);
        login.getDetails();
        login.checkData();
    }
```

DBMod Class:

```
package estorage;

import java.sql.*;

public class DBMod {
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.exasol.jdbc.EXADriver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:exa:192.168.56.101";
    static final String USER = "sys";
    static final String PASS = "exasol";

    //Add Entry to Database Method
    public void Add(String f, String l, String p, String u) {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement st = null;
        try {
            //Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.exasol.jdbc.EXADriver");

            //Open connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            //Execute a Query
            System.out.println("Adding details...");
            String insert = "INSERT INTO ES.USERS (firstname, lastname, username, password)" +
                         "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            st = con.prepareStatement(insert);
            st.setString(1, f);
            st.setString(2, l);
            st.setString(3, u);
            st.setString(4, p);
            st.executeUpdate();


            //Extract all records & Update
            insert = "SELECT * FROM ES.USERS";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(insert);

             while(rs.next()) {
                //Retrive data by column name
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String firstName = rs.getString("firstname");
                String lastName = rs.getString("lastname");
                String username = rs.getString("username");
                String password = rs.getString("password");

                //Display values
                System.out.print("ID: " + id);
                System.out.print(", First Name: " + firstName);
                System.out.print(", Last Name: " + lastName);
                System.out.print(", Username: " + username);
                System.out.println(", Password: " + password);
            }
            rs.close();
        }

        catch (SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if(st != null)
                    con.close();              
            }
            catch(SQLException se) {

            }
            try {
                if(con != null)
                    con.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    //Get data from Database method
    public void getData(String u) {
        String username = null;
        String password = null;
        GetLogin details = new GetLogin(username, password);
         Connection con = null;
         PreparedStatement st = null;
         try {
             //Register JDBC driver
             Class.forName("com.exasol.jdbc.EXADriver");

             //Open connection
             System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
             con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
             System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

             //Execute a Query
             System.out.println("Retrieving details...");
             String data = "SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM ES.USERS WHERE USERNAME = ?";
             st = con.prepareStatement(data);
             st.setString(1, u);
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

              while(rs.next()) {
                 //Retrive data by column name
                 username = rs.getString("USERNAME");
                 password = rs.getString("PASSWORD");

                 //Display values
                 System.out.println();
                 System.out.println();
                 System.out.println();
                 System.out.println();
                 System.out.println();
                 System.out.println("Send to method");
                details.DBDetails(username, password);
                System.out.println(username);
                System.out.println(password);
                System.out.println("End DB Method");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();


             }
             rs.close();
             System.out.println(username);
             System.out.println(password);
         }

         catch (SQLException se){
             se.printStackTrace();
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         finally {
             try {
                 if(st != null)
                     con.close();              
             }
             catch(SQLException se) {

             }
             try {
                 if(con != null)
                     con.close();
             }
             catch(SQLException se) {
                 se.printStackTrace();
             }

         }

     }
```

GetLogin class:

```
private String u;
private String p;
private String dbU;
private String dbP;
private String userU;
private String userP;

GetLogin(String username, String password){

    u = username;
    p = password;

}

public void getDBDetails (String u) {
    DBMod details = new DBMod();
    details.getData(u);
}

public void DBDetails(String username, String password) {
    dbU = username;
    dbP = password;
    System.out.println(dbU);
    System.out.println(dbP);

}

public void userDetails(String username, String password) {
    userU = username;
    userP = password;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(userU);
    System.out.println(userP);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
}

public void checkData(){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(dbU);
    System.out.println(dbP);
    System.out.println(userU);
    System.out.println(userP);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

   if (userU.equals(dbU) && userP.equals(dbP)) {
       System.out.println("Sign in Successful!");
   }
   else {
       System.out.println("Incorrect username or password");
   }
} 

public void getDetails() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(dbU + " " + dbP);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

}
```

Comment: this is a program and a half isnt it

Comment: Why are you asking the internet where the issue is... just step through it with a debugger......

Comment: Yeah xD big one and its extremely frustrating to have such a tiny minor issue. Been driving me insane for the past 2 hours.

Comment: I have attempted to go through with debugger but doesn't get me very far with the javaFX pane opening. Apologies for the amount of stuff here and any pain caused during reading

Comment: unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them ;)

Comment: related: don't quite get how/where you connect/sync the login defined as local field in your db code with the login defined in the controller ..

Comment: The first thing you should do is remove most of `System.out.println();` and use `\n` properly.

Comment: ... and please stick to signature conventions of getters/setters: if you name a method getSomething, the method is expected to return a value .. without sticking to conventions, it's extremely hard to read your code (and I love reading code :)

Comment: @kleopatra many apologies xD I am in a stage of frustration right now adding code willy nilly in attempt to make it work. I usually clean up after.

Comment: well, you confuse yourself ;) take a step back, name the methods by what they do, stick to conventions ... then you'll seee at a glance how that clashes with your expectations

Comment: @kleopatra: good to see you here. Are you now delving into the JavaFX world?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels hey .. yeah, what else can a java desktop gal do nowadays :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, somewhere between completing the getData method and calling the checkData method both variable dbU and dbP are set to null and I can't find where or why...

No, they are never set to a value different to `null`, at least not for the instance you're calling `checkData` with. In your `getData` method you create a different instance of the `GetData` class and set the information for this new instance, not the existing one.

You could fix this by passing the `GetData` instance as parameter instead of creating a new one in the `getData` method:

```
void getData(String u, GetData details) {
    ...
}
```

```
public void getDBDetails (String u) {
    DBMod details = new DBMod();
    details.getData(u, this);
}
```

---

However I recommend rewriting the program

```
boolean checkLoginData(String username, String password) {
    DBMod dbmod = new DBMod();
    return password != null && password.equals(dbmod.getData(username));
}
```

```
public String getData(String u) {
    try {
         //Register JDBC driver
         Class.forName("com.exasol.jdbc.EXADriver");

         try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS)) {
             //Execute a Query
             String data = "SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM ES.USERS WHERE USERNAME = ?";
             PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(data);
             st.setString(1, u);

             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

             if (rs.next()) {
                 return rs.getString("PASSWORD");
             } else {
                 return null;
             }
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     return null;

 }
```

Much simpler, isn't it?

Comment: yeah, that's a possibility - now our colleague only needs to start listening :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Rather frustrated and at the point of rage quit anyway so will likely re-write. Am fairly new to this and doing it as a school project. My apologies for not providing the most elegant of solution or code.

Comment: I'm a little lost with your code. I understand its much simpler and what it does I just don't know how to handle the return to move onto the next pane as in to tell if login has been confirmed or not. Mind explaining to a noob?

Comment: @MarkSharpe Just do `if (checkLoginData(txtUserName.getText(), txtPassword.getText()) ) { /* login is successful... */}`.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't check your code completely but 
Look into this part of the code

```
 public void getData(String u) {
    String username = null;
    String password = null;
    GetLogin details = new GetLogin(username, password);
```

You are initiating the class with username and password as null

Comment: Yeah thought it might be that but checked and isn't. After looking further it might be the finally clause at the end of the DBMod Class. Will try to fix from there.

Comment: Tried did nothing so still completely lost.

Comment: Im sure its not the finally that causes this issue. Try to pass your username and password to the getData method and initiate the GetLogin class with those variables instead of null

Comment: Nope tried that still coming up as null regardless.

Comment: @MarkSharpe the nulls certainly aren't quite right - but I suspect that the fishynes is the local field GetLogin inside the DBMod.getData - try to pass-in your GetLogin instead

Comment: From my plentiful and strategically placed print statements I get the following:
from calling details.DBDetails(username, password) they are correct.
then from inside the actual DBDetails method they are still printing correctly.
Then still inside the getData method at the end Its still correct
However when it goes back out and calls the getDetails method it is now printing null null
and again when I print from within checkData it is null null.

Comment: @MarkSharpe that's because details is a LOCAL field in getData ... arent you listening ;) How do you expect its content to be transfered into the login of your controller, that would be magic :))

Answer (score -3):

getDBDetails() is defined as looking for two arguments, but your call to it sends only one.

Comment: No its not, it takes only one string